# How to solve red explanation mark in eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse

When i open existing project of eclipse it will be show red explanation mark on project name
here is my screen shot of project folder
[image]

And my project properties screen shot is below
so how to solve the android dependencies in this

[image]

[image]

So how can i solve this error

Comment: Why don't you use Android Studio?

Comment: Does the Android Support App Compat jar exists in path? Also, suggest to use Android Studio instead.

Comment: this is library issue. Make sure you are importing and providing all required libraries to your project

Answer (score 0):

It means there is a problem with the build path in your project. If it is an android project then it mostly means the target value specified in project.properties file cannot be found. This can also be caused because of other kinds of built problems. But it is shown mostly for built problems only. See [here](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6-201006080911/eclipse-news-part2.html#JavaViews) for more details. It is about built error decorater seen in eclipse.

[image]